# Phantom update in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

After clicking 'Save' to update a particular model in Django admin, I am returned back to the list view with a message stating that 'The [model] was changed successfully.'. The issue is that the model was not changed. The list view which contains the column I updated does not reflect the modified text.

I have over-written the model's Save method to include a print statement as well as a call to it's parent class.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'boom!'
        super(Blurb, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The model's Save method is not called (no 'boom!' output to the console). I have no issue adding new data to this model, it's just the update that does not work.

Any ideas on what the issue may be, or at least how I could debug it further?

Comment: have you modified the ModelAdmin save_model() method?

Comment: Yes, and the issue was in there. I completely forgot about that method. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turning Yuji's comment into an actual answer:

If you have phantom edits, you might want to check the [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) save_model() method.